# Why on earth is bottom 0 not working here?

Tags: css

Could someone please tell me why the `div` block `#contentbottom1` doesn't show up if i set it to `bottom: 0;`?
If I set it to, let's say, `bottom: 15vh` it shows up. I need this to work because I have to set both headlines together `9.2vh` from the bottom.
OFC I know how tangly me headline attribution is. ;)

```css
html,body { 
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  color       : #fff;
  font-size   : 100%; /* def: 16px */ 
  font-family : Times New Roman;
  }
h1 {
  margin  : 0;
  padding : 0;
  }
#container1 {   /* ------------ Container 1  */
  position   : relative;
  background : #4e7690 !important;
  width      : 100vw;
  height     : 100vh;
  max-width  : 100%;
  }
#header1 {    
  position   : relative;
  height     : 15vh;
  background : #c5c7c6  
  }
#header1 h1 {
  position    : absolute;
  text-align  : center;
  bottom      : 3vh;
  left        : 0;
  right       : 0;
  font-height : 3.8vh;
  }
#content1 {
  position  : relative;
  width     : 100vw;
  height    : 100vh;
  max-width : 100%;
  }
#content1 h1 {
  position    : relative;
  padding     : 0;
  margin      : 0;
  padding-top : 8.8vh;
  text-align  : center;
  font-size   : 5vh;
  line-height : 5vh;
  font-weight : 300;
  }
#content1 h3 {
  position    : relative;
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  padding-top : 3.9vh;
  text-align  : center;
  font-size   : 1.82vh;
  font-weight : 900;
  }
#content1 h4 {
  position    : relative;
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  padding-top : 1.93vh;
  text-align  : center;
  font-size   : 1.82vh;
  font-weight : 900;
  }
#content1 h2 {
  /*
  position    : absolute; 
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  left        : 0;
  right       : 0;
  */
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  /*
  padding-top : 1.93vh;
  */
  text-align  : center;
  font-size   : 5vh;
  line-height : 5vh;
  font-weight : 300;
  }
#content1 h5 {
  /*
  position    : absolute;
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  bottom      : 10.45vh;
  left        : 0;
  right       : 0;
  */
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  text-align  : center;
  padding-top : 3vh;
  font-size   : 5vh;
  line-height : 5vh;
  font-weight : 300;
  }
#contentbottom1 {
  position : absolute;
  margin   : 0;
  padding  : 0;
  bottom   : 15vh;
  left     : 0;
  right    : 0;
  }
#footcontent {
  position   : absolute;
  bottom     : 0;
  text-align : center;
  /*
  width      : 100vw;
  max-width  : 100%;
  */
  background : #f00;
  }
#footcontent h5 {
  position   : relative;
  text-align : center;
  color      : #fff;
  }
#anker1 {
  position         : absolute;
  right            : 4.42vh;
  top              : 4.19vh;
  background-color : #00f;
  width            : 9.2vh;
  height           : 9.2vh;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="header1">
    <h1>    123</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="content1">
    <h1>DIE DOLLE ÜBERSCHRIFT</h1>
    <h3>Markthalle 14 - Ö-12345 Neubergen</h3>
    <h4>poststelle@oberhausen.de - www.schwervermittelbar.de</h4>

    <div id="anker1"></div>
    <div id="contentbottom1">
      <h2>Fuchs du hast die Ganz gestohlen gib sie wieder her</h2>
      <h5>Sonst wird dich der Jäger holen mit dem Schießgewehr</h5>
    </div>
    
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question, not a third party site

Comment: because the parent container is 100vh tall but it starts after the header1 which is 15vh tall, so the height exceeds the boundary of the viewport by 15vh. You probably want to set the container height to 85vh, not 100vh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FabrizioCalderanlovestrees had the right answer.
The parent element is 100vh high, and the header shoves the content down by 15vh so there is only 85vh left - not 100vh.